# If - else statements

Tags: java, if-statement

I am having an issue with my logic in my if else statements.

```
  String[] keywords = { "day", "What book", "office", "hour",
            "e-mail" };

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = null;
    /* -end init- */

    System.out.println("Welcome ");
    System.out.println("What's on your mind?");
    do {
        System.out.print("> ");
        input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        for (String keyword : keywords) {

            if (input.contains(keyword)) {
                parseFile(keyword);

            }

            else  {
                Writer();

            }
        }
        break;
    } while (input.equalsIgnoreCase("bye"));
    System.out.println("Have a good day!");

}
 }
```

For some reason the first IF statement is ignored. Can someone give me some suggestions. Thanks

Comment: What is your `input` and what are the `keywords`? It is not "ignored", it's probably just always `false`

Comment: @OriLentz The second if executes. This means it is not always false.

Comment: there could be two reasons, either the control is not getting inside the for loop, or the condition mentioned in if is false, need some more code to understand

Comment: Okay, then how do you know that's is always ignored? What does `parseFile` do? Try replacing it with a `System.out.println` and see if it ever gets there

Comment: The way this is written, `Writer()` will be called if the input contains _anything_ that's not on the list of keywords.  Is that what you intended?  If not, then please try to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Yes Writer() is called when nothing is found on the list

Comment: After you lower-case your input, it will _never_ contain the strings `"Cs 377"` or `"What book"`.

Comment: Your do-while is backward.  You've told it to repeat the loop **while** the input string is `bye`.  That means that as soon as you enter something else, and it goes through the loop once, it will exit right away.  Although it doesn't really matter, because your `break` statement will exit the loop before it even tests the `while` condition.

Comment: Suppose you type in `"lectures"`.  The way your code is written, it will call `parseFile` once and `Writer()` 21 times.  (That's what David was getting at).  If you want to call `Writer()` when _nothing_ is found, you need to keep track of whether you find anything with, perhaps, a `boolean found` that you set to `true` when you find something--and then only check _after_ the `for` loop is done to see if you need to call `Writer()`.

Comment: okay i appreciate the comment . I did this and only the parseFile () is executed. Even when i type something that is not found.                                            for (String keyword : keywords) {
    
    if (input.contains(keyword)) {
     found = true;
     parseFile(keyword);
     //break;
    }
   }

    if(!found) {
     Writer();
    //break;
    }

Comment: Are you saying that it thinks the keyword is "found" even though it shouldn't be?  If that's the case, please use `System.out.println` and have your program output `input` and `keyword`, and let us know what they are.

Comment: Welcome 
What's on your mind?
> where is the lecture
> when is the lecture time
the lecture time is at 5
>

Answer (score 2):

using map will reduce the looping for whole array for every time to check if .

Comment: Okay so I am new to this, How would a map make this easier ?

Comment: I missed the logic i thought you are searching  one word in a Array  but you are checking if any of the world match  in the array against User input , on side note  The HashMap provides constant-time performance for the basic operations (get and put).

Answer (score 1):

I tried running the program and it worked well. If suppose i entered `day`as input. Then it goes inside `if` once and inside else for (length of keywords-1)  time. Please check if you are not entering the value same as given in keywords array.

```
package myApp;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Client{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] keywords = { "day", "Cs 377", "What book", "office", "hour",
                "e-mail", "name", "major", "student e-mail", "group id",
                "lectures", "lecture room", "lecture time",
                "number of lectures", "current lecture",
                "topics of current lecture", "number of test",
                "date of a test", "number of assignments", "sure",
                "current assignment", "due day" };

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = null;
        /* -end init- */

        System.out.println("Welcome ");
        System.out.println("What's on your mind?");
        do {
            System.out.print("> ");
            input = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
            for (String keyword : keywords) {

                if (input.contains(keyword)) {
                    System.out.println("KEYWORD:" + keyword);
                    break;
                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("KEYWORD not found");

                }
            }
            break;
        } while (input.equalsIgnoreCase("bye"));
        System.out.println("Have a good day!");

    }
}
```

I replaced few things inside if and else with sysout. 
I entered day in input and got following result.

```
Welcome 
What's on your mind?
> day
KEYWORD:day
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
KEYWORD not found
Have a good day!
```

This output is very well understandable. If you find it difficult, comment the problem you face below.

Comment: My problem is going through the loop one time. If day is found print day followed by have a good day. else day is not found sysout Keyword not found

Comment: So would it be logical to have only one "If" statement inside the for loop and have another if statement outside the for loop that checks to see if the not found? For example  for                                                                                     (String keyword : keywords) {
    found = true;
    if (input.contains(keyword)) {
     parseFile(keyword);
     //break;
    }
   }

    if(!found) {
     Writer();
    //break;
    }

Comment: just put a break inside for loop's if condition.

Comment: See the edited answer. P.S. Please accept the answer if it solved the problem

Comment: break actually takes the control out of the loop, it is written in. First break will take it out of for while the second, out of dowhile